# Cypress typescript error src/index.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)how to fix

Tags: typescript, cypress

I want to create a custom command. I couldn't work out how to get my custom command just to return a value without having to use this disgusting .then syntax which doesn't have a good developer experience (Basically retrieving a bunch of creds)

I just want a simple function:

```
getCred(username_key)
```

and that returns a username instead of:

```
cy.getCreds(username_key).then(cred=> {
etc
})
```

So I have the following function:

```
export const credentialsAre =  (key) => {
    const parsedata = JSON.parse(testdata)
    console.log("key is: ", key);
    return parsedata.Credentials[key]
}
```

but importing it in another repo I get this error:

```
import {credentialsAre} from '@mycustomcommands'
File '/src/index.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: Can you specify a bit what you mean by "importing it in another repo"? Where are you exporting the function and where are you trying to import it?

Comment: @SebastianoVierk I created a seperate NPM package for the custom commands and am importing this package into a different repo